# Ansible failed to connect to the host via ssh, but ssh command works

Tags: ssh, ansible

From `inventory.yml`:

```yaml
myhost:
  ansible_host: myhost # actually it was ansible_ssh_host (see my answer)
  ansible_user: myuser # actually it was ansible_ssh_user (see my answer)
  ansible_pass: mypass # actually it was ansible_ssh_pass (see my answer)
```

So far, Ansible worked fine. I could also `ssh myuser@myhost`.

Then, I changed the ssh port from default 22 to 23 and edited the `inventory.yml`:

```yaml
myhost:
  ansible_host: myhost
  ansible_user: myuser
  ansible_pass: mypass # THE PROBLEM! Must be ansible_ssh_pass. (see my answer)
  ansible_port: 23
```

As expected, I can `ssh myuser@myhost -p 23`, but Ansible gives the error:

```
fatal: [staging]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: myuser@myhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).", "unreachable": true}
```

What could be causing the error?

Comment: try adding ansible_port: 23 as the first parameter at the top. 
myhost:
  ansible_port: 23
  ansible_host: myhost
  ansible_user: myuser
  ansible_pass: mypass

Comment: Thank you. Though, the problem was something else.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is quite unexpected and slightly embarrassing:

While changing the SSH port, I also read this:

> Ansible 2.0 has deprecated the “ssh” from ansible_ssh_user,
>   ansible_ssh_host, and ansible_ssh_port to become ansible_user,
>   ansible_host, and ansible_port.

I edited `inventory.yml` a bit too eagerly, as I also changed `ansible_ssh_pass` to `ansible_pass`. Hence: missing password -> permission denied.

So, my question had been phrased in a wrong way. I have updated it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The variable for password is `ansible_password`. See [documentation here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters) to create your `inventory.yml` properly.

Notice that you should never store your password in plain text, but use a vault in stead.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, where key based ssh is only allowed, ansible ping was failing with -

`"msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey).",`

The inventory file had entry for `ansible_user=$user`. Removing entry from inventory file helped.

My environment :

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.9.27
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/USER_NAME/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.12 (default, Mar  1 2021, 11:38:31) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
```